# Sending control key combinations to an element in watir-webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

How can you send control key combination to an element when using watir-webdriver?

Currently I am able to send a string to the element with the following code;

```
$browser.frame(:id,"ws-txt-editor").div(:id,"proxy").send_keys("\b")
```

or

```
$browser.frame(:id,"ws-txt-editor").div(:id,"proxy").send_keys(myAttrib[2])
```

but how do I send arrow keys or things like CTRL-A, CTRL-C or CTRL-V?

I am using watir-webdriver version 0.2.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
element.send_keys :arrow_down
element.send_keys [:control, "a"], :backspace
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to include anything else to get those to work or do they come in with the require "watir-webdriver" statement?

Comment: You don't need to include anything else.

Comment: Thanks, the control code didn't seem to have the desired effect but I think that might be down to our jQuery based rich content editor rather than the send keys method.